# Overlay pcolormeshes in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to overlay differently colored regions with pcolormesh. The masked regions do indeed not show up, but they cover other complementary regions. Below is an example where I first plot both regions separately (so the masking works nicely), but then I want to overlay them, however the second one covers the first one. How can I get a plot where the different regions are colored differently?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

xi=np.linspace(0,10,100)
yi=np.linspace(0,10,150)

x=0.5*(xi[1:]+xi[:-1])
y=0.5*(yi[1:]+yi[:-1])

X,Y=np.meshgrid(x,y)

Z = np.exp(-(X-5)**2-(Y-5)**2)

Z1 = Z.copy()
Z1[(X+Y)<10]=np.nan

Z2 = Z.copy()
Z2[(X+Y)>=10]=np.nan

plt.figure(figsize=(4,12),tight_layout=True)

plt.subplot(3,1,1)
plt.pcolormesh(x,y,Z1,cmap='Greens',vmin=0,vmax=Z.max())

plt.subplot(3,1,2)
plt.pcolormesh(x,y,Z2,cmap='Blues',vmin=0,vmax=Z.max())

plt.subplot(3,1,3)
plt.pcolormesh(x,y,Z1,cmap='Greens',vmin=0,vmax=Z.max())
plt.pcolormesh(x,y,Z2,cmap='Blues',vmin=0,vmax=Z.max())
```

[image]

## Edit:

I should add that the whole thing works nice if I use `contourf` instead of `pcolormesh`, but then there is an ugly empty area in between them, as shown below. Alternate question: how do I get rid of that area when using `contourf`?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make the masked array with the numpy masking module instead of just doing np.nan. Change `Z2[(X+Y)>=10]=np.nan` to `Z2 = np.ma.masked_array(Z, (X+Y)>=10)`.

Comment: I tried that before in my production code, but the results were the same. But for the example above, it indeed works. Will need to figure out what went wrong in my code.